# Arraylist as parameter in method and add data in multiple Arraylist

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a java-programme:

```
    public class Faculty 
    {
    String facultyName;
    Double gemavailable; 
    }

    public class Session
   {
    String coursename;
    float noofhours;
    ArrayList<Faculty> faculty=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class TrainingInstitute 
   {
   ArrayList<Faculty> faculty=new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<Session> session=new ArrayList<>();

   public void takeASession(String coursename,float hours,ArrayList<Faculty> faculty)
   {
    Session s=new Session(coursename, hours, faculty);
    session.add(s);
   }
```

And I have the main class which looks like:

```
    public class TrainingController 
    {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TrainingInstitute t=new TrainingInstitute();

        t.takeASession("java", 5,f1);
    }
```

My main motive is to create a session object by setting the course name,faculty who had taken the course and duration of the course.And the session object is added to the sessionTaken list of Training Institute.
How would i do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is unclear what you need to do other than what you have posted. What about the above code is not working?

Comment: @cyril: Lol..you can say that.

Comment: @JohnB I am sorry,It is not able to call the takeASession from the main class

Comment: @sunleo didn't it is in `TrainingInstitute`. Might want to be carefull with phrases like `your design ... is bad`

Comment: is `f1` an `ArrayList`? When you state `not able to call`, what does that mean? Do you get a compile error what is the compile error? These are the bits of information that will lead you to the answer and will help us help you. Note, generally methods should take interfaces like `List` instead of implementations like `ArrayList`.

Comment: @JohnB no,f1 is an object of faculty.

Comment: @JohnB sorry for inconvenient phrase will correct myself.

Comment: So it sounds like Arun solution is correct (regarding creating an `ArrayList`). Although I would use `t.takeASession("java", 5, Lists.newArrayList(f1));` Is it? If so mark it as accepted. If not, why not?

Comment: @coolmego is it ok to modify a little of the code see my answer?

Comment: @coolmego please accept an answer if by chance one is useful, that's how the site works ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this

Either you could have an overload constructor on `Session` class and push in one faculty to start with and then incrementally add faculty using the `addFaculty` method.

```
    public class Session {

    private String coursename;
    private float noofhours;
    private ArrayList<Faculty> faculty=new ArrayList<Faculty>();

    public Session(String courseName, float noOfHours, Faculty faculty){
        this.coursename=courseName;
        this.noofhours=noOfHours;
        this.faculty.add(faculty);

    }

    public Session(String courseName, float noOfHours, ArrayList<Faculty> faculty){
        this.coursename=courseName;
        this.noofhours=noOfHours;
        this.faculty=faculty;

    }

    public void addFaculty(Faculty faculty){
        this.faculty.add(faculty);

    }


}
```

Else you could do a

```
 t.takeASession("java", 5,new ArrayList(){{add(f1);}});
```

Comment: You have included Faculty arraylist in Session,what will this will actually do.?

Comment: I guess the original code has a Faculty ArrayList in the Session. Was just playing along.

Comment: Arun, Guava's `Lists` class has a `newArrayList(T...values)` method that will do the `new Arraylist` above in a more consise manner. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html

Comment: @JohnB Cool. I learnt something new today because of you. Thanks !!

Comment: NP, If you haven't checked out Guava before, take a look. It is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to instantiate your `Session` object as follows:

```
Session s = new Session(coursename, hours, faculty);
```

you need to define a constructor like that in you `Session` class

```
public class Session {
    private String courseName;
    private float noOfHours;
    private List<Faculty> faculties;

    public Session(String courseName, float noOfHrs, List<Faculty> faculties) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.noOfHours = noOfHrs;
        this.faculties = faculties;
    }
```

You should use `List` (the interface) instead of `ArrayList` (an implementation) as the type of your list. Also, you should ecapsulte the fields in your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do

```
public class TrainingController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Faculty faculty1 = new Faculty("NY", 200.0);
        List<Faculty> faculties = new ArrayList<Faculty>();
        faculties.add(faculty1);

        TrainingInstitute training=new TrainingInstitute();
        training.takeASession( new Session("java", 5, faculties) );
        training.takeASession( new Session("php", 4, faculties) );
        System.out.println(training);
    }
}

class Faculty {
    String facultyName;
    double gemavailable;
    public Faculty(String facultyName, Double gemavailable) {
        this.facultyName = facultyName;
        this.gemavailable = gemavailable;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return facultyName+" "+gemavailable;
    }
}

class Session {
    String coursename;
    float noofhours;
    List<Faculty> faculties;
    public Session(String coursename, float noofhours,
            List<Faculty> faculties) {
        this.coursename = coursename;
        this.noofhours = noofhours;
        this.faculties = faculties;
    }
    public List<Faculty> getFaculties() {
        return faculties;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return coursename+" "+noofhours+" "+faculties;
    }
}

class TrainingInstitute {
    Set<Faculty> faculties = new HashSet<Faculty>();
    List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();
    public void takeASession(Session session) {
        sessions.add(session);
        faculties.addAll(session.getFaculties());
        for (Faculty faculty: faculties){
            faculty.gemavailable -= session.noofhours;
        }
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "faculties: " + faculties + "\nsessions:" + sessions;
    }
}
```

Comment: outputs: 
faculties: [NY 191.0]
sessions:[java 5.0 [NY 191.0], php 4.0 [NY 191.0]]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting late,but this is how i got my prorram run:
    public class TrainingInstitute 
    {

```
private ArrayList<Faculty> faculty1=new ArrayList<Faculty>();
private ArrayList<Session> session1=new ArrayList<Session>();

public void takeASession(String facname,String cname,float noOfhours)
{

        Session s=new Session(cname, noOfhours,new Faculty(facname));
        session1.add(s);
        System.out.println("The session for"+""+facname+"is added and the size is:"+session1.size());
}
```